# Vba code to check if produced pieces are greater than 104%

Tags: vba, excel

Hello I am Trying To Create an Vba Code Check, a Po numbers Produced pieces is above 104%, so the program would take the Po. and the produces pieces as input and would check if the produced pieces exceeds 104% and return an error.

This Would allow the user to input the Po.number

```
Public Sub Pobox_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
Dim x As Integer
x = 1
Dim trovato As Boolean 'found=trovato
trovato = False
'Dim Labelstyle, Labelcolor As String

'Sheets("PO summary").Activate
Do Until Sheet2.Cells(1 + x, 1) = ""
If Sheet2.Cells(1 + x, 1) = Pobox.Value Or Sheet2.Cells(1 + x, 10) = Pobox.Value Then
    Labelstyle = Sheet2.Cells(1 + x, 13)
    Labelcolor = Sheet2.Cells(1 + x, 14)
    trovato = True
End If
x = x + 1
Loop
'Sheets("INSERT").Activate

If trovato = False And Pobox.Value <> "" Then
MsgBox "PO not valid"
Pobox.Value = ""
End If

End Sub
```

And This Would Search for the Po.Number and if found, it would then Check for Size same row but different column, and lastly if it finds the last two it would check the Produced Pieces and Check if its greater than 104% then it would return error

```
Private Sub Lbox_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
If KeyAscii > 58 Or KeyAscii < 48 Then
KeyAscii = 0
MsgBox ("enter number ")
Lbox.SetFocus
End If
With Worksheets(4).Range("j2:j1048576")
Set c = .Find(Pobox.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
End With
If Not c Is Nothing Then
With Worksheets(4).Range("s2:s1048576")
 Set d = .Find("L", LookIn:=xlValues)
 End With
  If Not d Is Nothing Then

 With Worksheets(4).Range("u2:u1048576")
 Set d = .Find("L", LookIn:=xlValues)
 End With
 If e > 1.04 Then
  MsgBox "Too Large "
  End If
  End If
  End If
  End Sub
```

Comment: What is the issue exactly?